# SharePoint javascript search list

Tags: javascript, listview, search, sharepoint, web-parts

list name: 'FAQ'
list view: All Items
column1: title
column2: body
column3: department

Code is suppose to have the same table inserted twice. the second webpart displays all of the entries. The first one is hidden and displays only what is returned from the search.

Currently both lists are not be displayed and no results are populating as well as the msgHTML and newFAQHtml

```js
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-listviewtable {display:none;} // hide all listviews on the page by css class
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".ms-listviewtable").eq(1).show();   // show 2nd listview table - Existing Questions/Answers
});

function searchList(){

 var list = $(".ms-listviewtable").eq(0);  // select 1st listview table - Search Results
 var searchInput = $("input[title=ListSearchText]");   // search box text
 var listItems = $(".ms-listviewtable:eq(0) tr:not(.ms-viewheadertr)");   // rows of the items in 1st listview table 
 var results = 0;    // search results flag
 var searchCol = $("#sfield")[0].selectedIndex;   // # of column in list to search - from dropdown

 if ( searchInput.val() != "" )
 {
    var statusDiv = $("#searchStatus");  // div to show status of search

    listItems.each(function() // for each item in our list
    {
        var cellValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq('+ searchCol + ')').text().toLowerCase();  //get text in cell, convert to lowercase to eliminate case-sensitivity
        var row = $(this);

           if (cellValue.indexOf( searchInput.val().toLowerCase() ) != -1) // does it match the search text
           { 
              row.show();
              results = 1;
           }
           else
           {
              row.hide();
           }

    });

    var msgHtml = "<div style='font-size:10pt;color:black;font-weight:normal;margin-left:13px;'><br/>Your search did not return any results.</div>";

    var newFAQHtml = "<div style='font-size:10pt;color:black;font-weight:normal;margin-left:13px;'><br/>Did our search return what your'e looking for?  If not, you may <a href='javascript:OpenPopUpPage(&quot;https://Lists/FAQ/NewForm.aspx&quot;);'>enter a new submission</a>.</div>";

    if (results > 0)
    {
      list.show();
      list.find('.ms-viewheadertr').show();
      statusDiv.html("Search results for: <b>" + searchInput.val() + "</b>");
    }
    else
    {
      list.hide();
      list.find('.ms-viewheadertr').hide();
      statusDiv.html("Search results for: <b>" + searchInput.val() + "</b>" + msgHtml);
    }

    searchInput.val("");
 }

}

</script>

<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) searchList()">
<span style="font-size: 10pt;color:black;font-weight:bold;">Please Select FAQ Category: </span>
<select id="sfield">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Title">Question</option>
<option value="Body">Category</option>
<option value="Department">Answer</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<input type=”text” id=”sText” title="ListSearchText" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="searchList();" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://Help.aspx">Clear Search</a><div>
<br/>&nbsp;

<div id="searchStatus" style="font-size:10pt;font:Tahoma;color:#385b98;width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: If the above code is in a webpart, which webpart is it in?

Comment: the content editor webpart points to the .txt where the code lives.

Comment: Any errors? Where do you have the content editor webpart with pointed code in comparison to the rest of the webparts? Possible code is running/erroring before other webparts are able to create the references?

Comment: no errors before webparts are created.